# Should we always cuddle a toddler when it cries?

Tags: infant, crying

Whenever our 3-month old baby cries, as soon as we cuddle her, she will stop crying.

My worry is:

- She will develop a habit out of this and grow too dependent on us cuddling her.

Should we leave her crying for a while to stop her demand cuddling so much?

Comment: Good question! Please have a look at the Q (and As) linked as a duplicate. If you feel it's not a duplicate, you can edit to explain why and flag for reopening, or you can ask in meta. Thanks! (I edited the tags; toddlers are older than infants.)

Comment: I'm a young dad and my Mom often lovingly tells me "You can not give a baby too much love and attention." And I've found it to be true I'm not saying you can't ever let a baby cry for a minute either, But I always make an extra effort to comfort my babies as quickly as I can while they are babies.  around 6- 9 months I've found my kids start crying if you take a toy away or move them when they don't want to be moved.  So I don't worry so much about letting them cry after that point.  But as a little baby the thing they need most is your love and attention.